# MS SQL count total items, but only once per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the total unique occurences of `NAME` from the MS SQL database, but only once for every user. Below is a sample of my data.

```
USERID      NAME
------------------------
1           name 1
1           name 1
1           name 1
2           name 1
2           name 2
2           name 3
3           name 1
3           name 1
3           name 3
4           name 1
```

If I use the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS total, name FROM TestTable GROUP BY name
```

I get the following results

```
7   name 1
1   name 2
2   name 3
```

But what I want is the result below. The query should ignore 2x `name 1` from user 1 and 1x `name 1` from user 3.

```
4   name 1
1   name 2
2   name 3
```

I have insufficient knowledge of SQL to get this to work, or to know the correct terms to use in the query. So there probably is a duplicate and if so, please point me to it.

Comment: why it should'n ignore the  name 1 of user 4

Comment: So you want to count distinct userid per name?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the amount of 4 should be calculated by ujsing `name 1` only once from each individual user, in this sample data there are 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use distinct userid for `count()`

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct userid) AS total, name FROM TestTable GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know you could use DISTINCT inside COUNT.

Answer (score 4):

use `distinct` and `count()` userid

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct userid) AS total, name FROM TestTable GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` to ignore duplicate counts :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERID) AS total, name 
FROM TestTable 
GROUP BY name;
```